# Java super class variable accessed outside of subclass?

Tags: java, inheritance, super

If I have three classes as follows:

```
package com.Bob.Marley;
public class SuperClass{
     protected int x = 0;
}

package com.Bob.Marley;
public class SubClass extends SuperClass{
    protected int x = 1;
}

package com.Bob.Marley;
public class TestClass{
    public static void main (String[] args){
        SubClass s = new SubClass();
        //print 1
        System.out.println(s.x);
        //how do I print the superclass variable?
        //I know inside SubClass I can access it with plain old super.x
        //but what about outside the subclass with a new object. 
    }
}
```

So the question is how would I print out 0 from the superclass of the new object s created in a separate class. System.out.println(s.super.x); does not work. I don't think it changes anything but I am using java 8.

Comment: @rgettman whoops yeh thanks edited

Answer (score 0):

The expression `s.super.x` is invalid here.  Whenever you prefix a `super.x` with something, it should be a type name, not a variable name, e.g. `SuperClass.super.x`.  However, this would be valid only inside the subclass for accessing the superclass of the *enclosing* class, which does not exist here.

Cast `x` to be a `SuperClass` so you can access the `x` declared in `Superclass`.

```
System.out.println( ((SuperClass) s).x);
```

or

```
SuperClass sc = (SuperClass) s;
System.out.println(sc.x);
```

This works because variable access is statically binded.  The type of the variable or expression determines the scope searched for variable access.

Comment: super.x is valid for non-enclosing subclasses correct if super.x is called inside the subclass?

Comment: Yes, `super.x` is only valid as code within the subclass.

Comment: And this follow up question may be confusing but say you int x. To get it in the subclass it is super.x; if the method was getX() in the super class then it would be super.getX(). So if all primitives were changed from the variable name to get<Variable Name>() as methods and all super.<Variable name> were converted to super.get<Variable name>() by the compiler. Would everything behave the same way in respect to public, protected, default, private in the subclass of same package, outside the sub same package,  in sub different package, outside sub different package, In other words, all combos.

Comment: Cause I cant find a complete chart on scope handling with respect to the super/subclass system inside and outside a package and all combinations, so if it can be summarized by treating it the same way as the getters with the same scope properties... it would be much easier to understand.

Answer (score 0):

**TL;DR: if you introduce a new field in a subclass, don't re-use a field name from the parent class. You gain nothing, only confusion and problems.**

If I understand correctly, you want `SubClass` instances to have two fields, one inherited from the `SuperClass` (for the discussion, let's rename that to `superX` to make things clearer), and one from the subclass itself (let's rename that to `subX`).

For a given `SubClass` instance, you want to be able to access both fields, `superX` and `subX` (of course, using different expressions). What makes things difficult in your code sample, is the fact that you chose to give both of them the same name `x`.

So, if you really want your instances to carry both fields, I'd recommend to rename them, so you don't have to use ugly tricks like casting to the `SuperClass`.

```
public class SuperClass{
     protected int superX = 0;
}

public class SubClass extends SuperClass{
    protected int subX = 1;
}
```

But, if `x` stands for the same property with the same meaning for both the super and the sub class, just with different initial values, then it doesn't make sense to have two different fields, and you should change the code to become:

```
public class SuperClass{
     protected int x = 0;
}

public class SubClass extends SuperClass{
    // constructor initializes the x field with 1.
    public SubClass(){
        x = 1;
    }
}
```

Of course, then it's impossible to get two different values from a single instance of `SubClass`.

Comment: Well this is a question I will need to know for the OCA exam which is full of useless crap and weird syntaxes that you won't see in the real world unless you're paired up with a very sucky programmer who, if they actually code like that should not be hired. But still thank you, that's the way I would normally code it... two different values.